# Tomcat - FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, filenotfoundexception

I have a web application deployed on my tomcat server.
My folder structure is TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/segnalazioni_degrado/config.

The config folder contains some properties files.
When I run my application in Development Mode (Eclipse) everything works fine, but since I deployed it on Tomcat I am getting the filenotfound exception.
This is the way I load the .properties file on the server:

```
[...]
Properties props = new Properties();
    try {
        props.load(new FileInputStream("config/DBconfig.properties"));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    url = props.getProperty("url");
    user = props.getProperty("user");
    password = props.getProperty("password");
[...]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every webapp has it's own classloader in tomcat. The `ClassLoader.getSystemResource`will use the system class loader that is used to load the bootstrap and the tomcat application. But the system class loader does not know anything about your webapp and it's classpath. Using the right class loader is essential.
There are a lot of solutions to access the correct classloader. One solution is to use [ClassLoader#getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource).

Please look into [this example](http://knowhow.amazers.net/space/dev/java+tips/Loading+properties+in+a+web+application)

Comment: Your solution, combined with @duffymo 's one, worked. But I had to manually add the classes folder inside WEB-INF, as it is not generated when I GWT-compile my project..do you know why?

Answer (score 1):

> Am I doing something wrong?

Obviously, yes.  You wouldn't be getting an exception if all was well.

You should load that resource as a stream from the classpath.

That means that your WAR should look like this:

```
WEB-INF/classes/config/DBconfig.properties
```

Since you're using Tomcat, I'd recommend learning how to set up a JNDI data source connection pool.  Externalize your database connection information that way.

Comment: What if i didn't want to change the folder structure?